# Cox-Regression : Continous Time Depended Variables?

Tags: cox-model

I'm analyzing the prepayment options on a data set of loans. In order to estimate the associated risk of my hazard rate, I want to analyse the effect of a continous time-dependend variable (interest rates) on the prepayment risk.

So far, I found out that modelling time-dependend variables in a Cox-Regression modell should not be an issue. However, in all books and papers time-depended variables were defined as discrete.
For example, unemployment( 0 if unemployed, 1 if employed) changes from 0 to 1 after several weeks. Hence only the "state" of the variable changes o.v.t. .

In my case, I have for exaxmple interest rates as a time-depenended covariate, which is continous and has a different value for every time step.
Can Cox-Regression model such continous time-dependend variables? 
If yes, how can u interpret them?

Thanks,

KS

Comment: How about use splines?

Comment: Sorry, no clue what u mean?